# CoreWebView2 remains null

Tags: c#, webview2

I have the following WPF code, wherein one method simply initializes the WebView2 and navigates to the given URL.
In the other method i.e. 'SendDataToWeb' , I need to post a webmessage as JSON object to the Angular app and here it fails saying 'CoreWebView2' is null.

```
        private readonly WebView2 webView2;
        private async void Initialize()
        {
            await webView2.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
            webView2.CoreWebView2.Navigate("http://localhost:4200/");
            webView2.CoreWebView2.WebMessageReceived += CoreWebView2_WebMessageReceived;
        }

        public void SendDataToWeb(string data)
        {
            // Serialize data to JSON
            var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);

            // Send JSON data to WebView2
            webView2.CoreWebView2.PostWebMessageAsJson(json);
          
        }
```

Comment: When do you call SendDataToWeb? You'll need to make sure you are awaiting Initialize() and only calling SendDataToWeb after that.

Comment: 'SendDataToWeb' is supposed to be called by the WPF host app where this user control is being added

Comment: Does that mean that `SendDataToWeb` can be called before the async `Initialize` call finishes? If so, you need to do something in your `SendDataToWeb` method to make sure `Initialize` has finished. Like store the Task result of calling `Initialize` as a member, and await that member in `SendDataToWeb`. Its not just that `CoreWebView2` is `null` if `Initialize` hasn't finished then you haven't called `Navigate` and you haven't added the `WebMessageReceived` event handler and whatever else you do in `Initialize`.